# Canvas centre 0,0 is top left how to make it centre of the screen?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an customview which draws a canvas, im trying to draw a circle at the centre 0,0 but that goes to the top left corner, I want it to be the centre of the screen, how do you go about moving the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the width and height of the canvas and then divide them by 2.

Code Example:

```
int CenterOfx = (int)canvas.getWidth()/2;
int CenterOfy = (int)canvas.getHeight()/2;

canvas.drawCircle(CenterOfx,CenterOfy,25f,paintLines);
```

you can also use the size of the screen to get the center values.